# Make a loop for random string generator

Tags: java, generator

//problem is system prints left, left, left.. or right, right, right... , trying to generate left, right, left, left, right...

```
import java.util.Random;
 class generate {
    
     public void runMycode() {
        
     }
     public static void main (String [] args) {
         
         
             
         String [] arr = {"left", "right"};
         Random random = new Random();

        
         int select = random.nextInt(arr.length); 
         int i;

         for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        
         System.out.println( arr[select]); 
        }
}
```

Comment: You call `random.nextInt()` only once.

Comment: move `select = random.nextInt(arr.length);` inside the for loop

Answer (score 3):

`int select = random.nextInt(arr.length);` Is what actually generates the random number, but this is only called once inside the code.

Instead you need to have it in the loop so it regenerates a number each iteration

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int select = random.nextInt(arr.length);       
    System.out.println( arr[select]); 
}
```